# php list function not echoing variable outside loop

Tags: php

Any idea why i can't echo $a outside the loop? what am i missing?

```
while (list($a) = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
     $b = $a; //where $a = 10
}

echo $a; //this echo's nothing.
echo $b; //this echo's 10
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$a` is reset to `NULL` when the while loop ends, so it outputs nothing. (and the loop isn't entered at this moment anymore, so `$b = $a` won't be executed anymore)

This is because `$db->fetch_array()` returns false when there are no rows left.